Unable to Delete Partitions on SSD and Reinstall Windows 11
Details:
MOTHERBOARD: MSI MAG B660 Tomahawk wifi ddr4
OS: Windows 11
Processor: Intel i7-12700
SSD: XPG S5 512 GB
Issue Description:
I was using my system to browse the internet when I suddenly encountered a blue screen error with the stop code "Registry Error." I attempted an automatic repair both with and without a bootable Windows 11 USB drive. I also tried restoring the system to a previous restore point but encountered errors with each attempt.
Next, I tried to reinstall Windows. However, during the installation process, I was unable to delete any partitions on my drive, receiving the error message: "We couldn't create a new partition." I then attempted to delete the SSD partitions using Command Prompt (accessed via Shift+F10 during installation) and DISKPART. I selected the disk and performed the clean operation, but when I ran the "create partition primary" command, I received the following error: "Virtual Disk Service error: The object is not found."
I then tried to format the drive by connecting it to another PC and using the Disk Management tool, but the SSD appeared as offline and I could not delete the partitions.
Following this, I created a bootable Ubuntu USB drive to delete the partitions using GParted and fdisk. Both tools showed errors, with GParted indicating the presence of EFI and Microsoft Reserved partitions marked in red. Despite trying to delete the partitions using the nvme-cli tool in Linux, I was unsuccessful.
Here is sudo smartctl -x /dev/nvme0 Output:
smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [x86_64-linux-6.8.0-31-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       XPG GAMMIX S5
Serial Number:                      2M442L1ES8HJ
Firmware Version:                   VC0S036H
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x1cc1
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x707c18
Controller ID:                      1
NVMe Version:                       1.4
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          512,110,190,592 [512 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            707c18 1b8ecca600
Local Time is:                      Fri May 31 07:36:50 2024 UTC
Firmware Updates (0x02):            1 Slot
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x0054):     DS_Mngmt Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Log Page Attributes (0x02):         Cmd_Eff_Lg
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         32 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     100 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     110 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     8.00W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     4.00W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     3.00W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0300W       -        -    3  3  3  3     5000   10000
 4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4    54000   45000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
- media has been placed in read only mode

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x08
Temperature:                        45 Celsius
Available Spare:                    6%
Available Spare Threshold:          32%
Percentage Used:                    1%
Data Units Read:                    33,644,728 [17.2 TB]
Data Units Written:                 21,386,221 [10.9 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 493,923,922
Host Write Commands:                230,227,110
Controller Busy Time:               0
Power Cycles:                       2,241
Power On Hours:                     3,440
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   364
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 8 of 8 entries)
No Errors Logged

Self-test Log (NVMe Log 0x06)
Self-test status: No self-test in progress
Num  Test_Description  Status                       Power_on_Hours  Failing_LBA  NSID Seg SCT Code
 0   Extended          Completed without error                3439            -     -   -   -    -
 1   Short             Completed without error                3439            -     -   -   -    -
 2   Extended          Completed without error                3439            -     -   -   -    -
 3   Short             Completed without error                3439            -     -   -   -    -


but only the Health test fail when i run sudo smartctl -H /dev/nvme0 with output:
smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [x86_64-linux-6.8.0-31-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
- media has been placed in read only mode

Gparted ss
CrystalDiskInfo
Questions:
What should I do next to delete all partitions and perform a clean installation of Windows 11?
Is there some kind of lock on my SSD set by Windows or BIOS settings? I've confirmed that my SSD does not have a physical lock.
Could the drive be write-protected?

@GauravKumar - Please stop providing critical information as an non-formatted temporary comment. [Edit] your question and format this information in a readable format having to report a half dozen comments is time consuming

I apologize for any inconvenience. I have now updated my question with SSD S.M.A.R.T obtain from smartctl.

I see that https://superuser.com/q/1844367/964771 is using the same SSD model; maybe the model is "not so nice" (replace with your favorite four-letter word).

If you have access to another computer, you'll want to grab the manufacturer's diagnostic tools and see if it has any write failures.
SSDs can have write failures but would still allow reads. I had a drive in this state and it could boot properly but couldn't write. Since it can boot, it looks like it is working, but eventually will crash due to lack of ability to complete any of the write commands.
The most sure-fire way to confirm this error is the diagnostic software from the manufacturer. Otherwise, you can try formatting it using another system.
